# Bootstrap modal not loading from AngularJs js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to show a bootstrap modal dialog using `$('#myModal').modal('show')` but it doesn't seems to work. I have checked that the bootstrap js is loading before the angular app js. But the modal dialog shows up when I write `$('#myModal').modal('show')` in browser console.

Comment: Always try to place a modal's HTML code in a top-level position in your document to avoid other components affecting the modal's appearance and/or functionality.

Comment: can you post code from the controller you're referencing

Comment: @LVarayut Thanks that worked. I placed my modal html high and the modal is getting activated from the AngularJs script

Answer (score 0):

In addition to placing the modal's HTML code in a top level position (as per LVarayut's suggestion), you may also want to look at [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), a set of Bootstrap components written by the `AngularJS` team.

UI Bootstrap includes a service called `$modal`, which will give you a cleaner way of interacting with modals, especially if you choose to create a separate controller at a later point in time.